# For Loops Help in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, loops, for-loop

Need your help with this?

I am trying match list newtracks(name of songs in folder) with lists filezto and album from spreadsheet.
If the name of songs in folder match list filezto and have an album of Nasb copy it to folders list(ordfldrtosrt) and if not nasb album copy songs to list(ntsubfldrs).

For some reason when ran the if statement does not synch them up in order to print that they match and copy the files to the folders. I have tried different option but cannot make it work.  Thanks in advance.

```py
albm = ["NASB", "NASB", "NASB", "NASB", "NTSB", "NTSB", "NTSB", "NTSB"]

newtracks = [
    "Track1.mp3",
    "Track2.mp3",
    "Track3.mp3",
    "Track4.mp3",
    "Track5.mp3",
    "Track5.mp3",
]

filezto = [
    "Track1.mp3",
    "Track2.mp3",
    "Track3.mp3",
    "Track4.mp3",
    "Track5.mp3",
    "Track5.mp3",
]

ordfldrtosrt = ["1-GEN-GENE", "2 - EXO - Exos", "3 - LEV - Lev", "4 - NUM - Numb"]

ntsubfldrs = ["1-MAT-Matt", "2 - MRK - Mar", "3 - LUK - LI", "4 - JHN - Jo"]

for album in albm:
    for newtracks, filezto, ordfldrtosrt, ntsubfldrs in (
        (ntk, ft, otm, nts)
        for ntk in newtracks
        for ft in filezto
        for otm in ordfldrtosrt
        for nts in ntsubfldrs
    ):
        if album == "Nasb" and newtracks == filezto:

            print("Yes", newtracks, " files to", filezto)

            # shutil.copy('C:\\Users\\mrdrj\\Desktop\\SJ\\NASB\\'+newtracks,  'D:\\Desktop\\pythonProject\\Nasb\\'+ ordfldrtosrt+'\\'+newtracks)
        else:
            print("No", newtracks, " files to", filezto)
            # shutil.copy('C:\\Users\\mrdrj\\Desktop\\SJ\\NASB\\'+newtracks,  'D:\\Desktop\\pythonProject\\Nasb\\'+ ntsubfldrs +'\\'+newtracks)
```

Comment: It's perfectly fine to leave out data but your use of 'etc' means syntax errors. `ntsubfldrs = =` is another syntax error. Please update your example so it at least works.  You hard-coded input, good, now tells what output you get and expect (with your fixed program).  Also, as this is python indent matter.

Comment: Use functions instead of 5 for-loops on one line.  After I fix the syntax errors I am left with "NameError: name 'filezto' is not defined".   You are making it really hard to help you.

Comment: Thanks for the edit.  When ran it cycle matches with duplicates values first example track1.mp3  track1.mp3 then it splits of and do track1.mp3 still and track2.mp3, track3.mp3, etc.  The outcome I am looking for is matching of newtracks with filezto and check to see if album is NASB if so copy song to folders from list. I am still new to python and still working my way through.  Is there a website that explan indent thought the indents were good. Thank you

Comment: Please update your question with this info.  All your code was indented in question so it meant I had to reformat to run it.

Comment: Why  does albm contain duplicate values?

Comment: Sorry when it pasted it reformatted.  They reason of duplicates the tracks are from two Albums NASB and NTSB.

Comment: With duplicate I mean why does the value NASB and  NTSB each occur 4 times so len(albm) is 8 instead of 2.

Comment: Sorry I tend to over explain so was trying to keep it minimal as possible. The reason for the duplicates in albums is due to the 1246 songs on a spreadsheet divideded into two Albums.  I wanted to match songs in folder in list (newtracks) to list filezto the title of the songs from spreasheet then copy them to the folders of lists ordfldrtosrt and ntsubfldrs which are values from the spreadsheet.  Thanks

Comment: No worries.  We will figure it out.  So ordfldrtosrt are paths for the album NASB and ntsubfldrs are paths for NTSB.  Your folder and spreadsheet has 5 tracks but ordfldrtosrt and ntsubfldrs only have 4 values each.  Please refer to my solution below.  I think the only thing you need to do is add another column to spreadsheet with those paths, then in the loop do `for album, path, track in spreadsheet:`.

Answer (score 0):

From your last comment, I am guessing that you have have a list of (album, track) from your `spreadsheet` and you are trying to match that up with a list of tracks from one of the albums in `folder`:

```
folder = [
    "Track1.mp3",
    "Track2.mp3",
    "Track3.mp3",
    "Track4.mp3",
    "Track5.mp3",
    "Track5.mp3",
]
spreadsheet = [
    ( "NASB", "Track1.mp3" ),
    ( "NASB", "Track2.mp3" ),
    ( "NASB", "Track3.mp3" ),
    ( "NASB", "Track4.mp3" ),
    ( "NASB", "Track5.mp3" ),
    ( "NASB", "Track5.mp3" ),
    ( "NTSB", "Track1.mp3" ),
    ( "NTSB", "Track2.mp3" ),
    ( "NTSB", "Track3.mp3" ),
    ( "NTSB", "Track4.mp3" ),
    ( "NTSB", "Track5.mp3" ),
    ( "NTSB", "Track5.mp3" )
]
for album, track in spreadsheet:
    if album == 'NASB' and track in folder:
        print('%s %s' % ('Yes', track))
    else:
        print('%s %s' % ('No', track))
```

with gives you the output:

```
Yes Track1.mp3
Yes Track2.mp3
Yes Track3.mp3
Yes Track4.mp3
Yes Track5.mp3
Yes Track5.mp3
No Track1.mp3
No Track2.mp3
No Track3.mp3
No Track4.mp3
No Track5.mp3
No Track5.mp3
```

Comment: Thanks. When in use for albm, track in spreadsheet: I get ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2). I used: spreadsheet = albm + title(spreadsheet columns) to join lists and use newtracks for the songs in the folder and albm.append(cb.value) and title title.append(tlt.value+'.mp3') are the values used.  I did not know you can also use the for loop in that fashion.  I am learning as well.  Thanks

Comment: Please update your question with current code. If your spreadsheet has separate values, keep them separate as it's usually easier to process, only concatenate when you need to.

Comment: Please see update:     for albm, track in spreadsheet:
        if albm == 'NASB' and track in newtracks:
            print('%s %s' % ('Yes', track))
        else:
            print('%s %s' % ('No', track))  The reason why I concatenate was to add the album and the songs.  title.append(tlt.value+'.mp3')   spreadsheet = albm + title

Comment: Well, sounds like this when you need to.  It might be easier for you to use a single format string: '%s%s' % (tlt.value, '.mp3') or whatever.  Good luck!

Comment: Thanks. I checked the length of spreadsheet it is is way over the amount value amount.  So right now I am looking for a way to combine column 1(Album) and column 14(title) to have the same values.  Like the spreadsheet list example.